# Manipulating URL bar with BHO

Tags: delphi, bho

I want to block some URLs using BHO. To check what URL the browser is going to, I'm using BeforeNavigate2 event. Then, inside this event, if the URL is prohibited, I do a Navigate2 event for my URL. But I wanted to manipulate what URL will appear in the bar. I don't wanted to show the URL that Navigate2 goes to. How could I do that using BHO?

Comment: I'd think that's something that the browser vendor would be particularly set on preventing it. But then what do I know about writing malware...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the address bar through the browser's interfaces will trigger a new navigation. You will likely have to use the Win32 API to locate the actual edit field and manipulate it directly. However, by doing a navigation to a real URL, the browser is likely to just overwrite your custom text anyway during the course of navigation progress.

Comment: That's not what I was expecting... So to change the URL bar text, I need get the handles/child handles of IE, then SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT) with the URL I wanted to show? Via BHO I can't set?

Comment: Is possible to subclass the handle of Url bar? Once the BHO is registered isn't possible to do something like:
IE_URLBAR_CLASSNAME = ('AddressDisplay Control');
instead of using FindWindow/FindWindowEx to get the handles? Then if I get the handle I can use WM_SETTEXT...